# Trying to Classify MNIST where pixels are shuffled with a seed.Why is it not working?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistics

I transformed the MNIST dataset as follows:(**X (70000 x 784)** is the **training** matrix)

```
np.random.seed(42)
def transform_X():
    for i in range(len(X[:,1])):
        np.random.shuffle(X[i,:])
```

I had thought that **shuffling the pixels in an image** would make the digits unrecognizable by humans,but the machine learning algorithms would still be able to learn from the images with shuffled pixels correctly.

I cannot understand the **mathematical reason** behind not learning. Do you think this should work and I should recheck my code for any mistakes?
I trained on **SVC** and **SGDClassifier** of sklearn.Results from both are just randomness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially setting each image to a (more or less) random image. And now you wonder why it is not learning? There is (almost) no data to learn from left.

Let me give you a similar example. Here is some (unshuffled) training data:

```
0 0 0 -> 0
0 0 1 -> 0
0 1 0 -> 0
0 1 1 -> 0
1 0 0 -> 1
1 0 1 -> 1
1 1 0 -> 1
1 1 1 -> 1
```

The pattern is pretty obvious: The first column is equal to the label. The next two columns are irrelevant. Now let me give you some shuffeled training data:

```
0 0 0 -> 0
0 1 0 -> 0
1 0 0 -> 0
0 1 1 -> 0
1 0 0 -> 1
1 1 0 -> 1
1 0 1 -> 1
1 1 1 -> 1
```

Good luck with finding the correct pattern there. And this is only 3 dimensional; things get much worse with more dimensions.

One thing that could work if you stored a random permutation and applied the same permutation to each image.

Comment: I thought that setting a seed to np.random will apply the same random permutation to each image.Am I mistaken about the use of seed?

Comment: @Kartikchincholikar Yes, you are wrong. Setting a seed makes sure the program generates the same pseudo-random numbers each time the program is executed. If you want the same permutation each time, you should generate the permutation once and pass it each time. I can give you an example after work (please remind me if I forget to do so)

Comment: Thank You.I looked it up and implemented the correct code.

Comment: You're welcome! Does it work now? How good are your results?

Comment: I would expect at least 80% accuracy for MNIST - or similar to what a MLP with a similar amout of parameters achieves (I'm not sure right now how much that is)

Comment: Yes,It works. I'm getting 94.3 cross validation accuracy using RandomForestClassifier of sklearn. It does recognize digits from what looks as pure randomness to us!

Comment: @Kartikchincholikar Nice! I guess there is not a (significant) differnce to the non-permutated version, right? Now it would be interesting to see if CNNs perform significantly different between permutated vs non-permutated. (I expect that they do)

Comment: Yup,No significant difference

Answer (score 1):

A good indication, although quite rough, if an algorithm is capable of solving a task (especially pattern recognition tasks) is to check if humans can. We evolved to be quite good at it.

Obviously, that might not always be true. But in your case, by shuffling you loose all the structure of the data. The only possible feature your ML algorithm can use is the number of pixels set vs unset (or the pixel values, for grayscale images), thus basically losing all the structure. The problem is that this is a bad feature since there is little correlation between the number of pixels set and the digit. There is no pattern left, and any attempt to learn a pattern is doomed to fail. Thus, your algorithm may:

- try to learn a pattern where there is none
- not have enough features to do the classification

or a combination of the 2.